# AngularJS not loading html into ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-seed

I've been looking at my app for ages now trying to find what's wrong but cannot for the life of me seem to find it.

Here's my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Ericsson KAS</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/eBootstrap.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="menu-container">
      <div id="menu-top" class="e-full-blend"></div>
      <div id="menu-bottom" class="gray-gradient">
        <img ng-src="images/econ.png" height="35" width="27" class="logo" />
        <center><h2 class="ericsson-capital-dark">Knowledge Assessment Solution<h2></center>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a    href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->

  <div id="main" class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" ng-view>
  </div>

  <div id="version-legend">Version: <span app-version></span></div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="partials/view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="partials/view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="partials/view3/view3.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'controllers',
  'view1',
  'view2',
  'view3',
  'myApp.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'partials/view1'});
}]);
```

And the first view/partial that for some reason is not being loaded into ng-view

view1.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

view1.html

```
<div id="first-view" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" ng-controller="View1Ctrl as firstController">
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="domain" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Domain</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="jobRole" class="col-xs-3 control-label">Job Role</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input list="browsers" class="form-control">
            <datalist id="browsers">
              <option value="Internet Explorer">
              <option value="Firefox">
              <option value="Chrome">
              <option value="Opera">
              <option value="Safari">
            </datalist>
        </div>
     </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="ButtonCtrl as bCntrl">
            <div>
            <a class="clean-link-light lower-right" href="#/view2"><button type="submit" class="e-btn  e-btn-success" >{{ bCntrl.nextButtonTitle }}</button></a>
            <button id="admin-button" type="submit" class="e-btn e-btn-default">{{ bCntrl.adminButtonTitle }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I have no idea what I've managed to do to stop it from working but it was working fine until I copied one of the partials folder to add a view4. That messed everything up and even tho I've removed view4 it's still not runnig.

Any help is more than apreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but in app.js

`$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'partials/view1'});`

and in view.js

`$routeProvider.when('/view1', {...}`

Try in view.js:

`$routeProvider.when('partials/view1', {...}`

Comment: Almost :) Turned out I hade to remove "partial" from the  $routeProvider. Thanks tho, you made me look in the right place!

Answer (score 0):

You may defined all your road into your app.js
Example :

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/login',
{
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
});

$routeProvider.when('/home/',
{
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'

});
```

and the default road

`$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});`